# Не работает Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables

Tags: c#

Заранее задал переменную в свойствах системы, назвал её **HOME=C:\Users\user_name**. Пытаюсь выполнить следующий код:

```
string path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%HOME%");
```

Но путь "не раскрывается". В чём ошибка?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Процесс при запуске получает "снимок" переменных окружения. И передает его дочерним процессам. Переменные, добавленные в свойтвах системы уже после после старта процесса, видны не будут.

В вашем случае, этот процесс - Visual Studio.

Перезапустите студию и все заработает.

Comment: спасибо, помогло!)))